# What is that address you see in a buffer overflow segmentation fault?

Tags: c

So basically every time I overflow a buffer, I see this:

```
 Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.                                 
 0x00007ffff7a47c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)                        
      at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56                         
      56      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory
 .
```

The **question** that I have is: what is `0x00007ffff7a47c37`?

it is pretty far from `RSP` and `RBP` and before the program throw the segmentation fault if I do:

```
(gdb) break 12
(gdb) x/x $rip                                                            
    0x400654 <main+94>:     0xe0558d48
```

it seems not to be RIP as well.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int dummy;
    int* rip = &dummy;
    printf("%p\n", rip);
    int *ret;
    char buf[20];
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    ret = buf;
    printf("%p:%s\n", ret, buf);

    return 0;
}
```

I run the script as `run $(perl -e 'print "A"x40')`

Answer (score 0):

It is the memory address of argv variable.

Answer (score 0):

> it seems not to be RIP as well.

Though it doesn't seem so to you, it may well be that there are code addresses far away from each other. Example:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f2b9480dd52 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000400479 in _start ()
```

The value `0x00007ffff7a47c37` is definitely the instruction pointer where the signal was raised. You can even use the `gdb` command `disas __GI_raise` to verify.